# Blazor Server Authorization with Custom Authentication State Provider

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-8.0

I'm a Former System Admin just started working with Blazor Server using latest and greatest .NET8 Framework so consider me noob in programming.

I have this Blazor Server App with Global Interactivity and I have created following Custom Authentication State Provider which is working fine.

```
public class CustomAuthenticationState(ILogger<CustomAuthenticationState> logger, ProtectedLocalStorage storage) : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly ProtectedLocalStorage _storage = storage;
    private readonly ILogger<CustomAuthenticationState> _logger = logger;
    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var user = await _storage.GetAsync<AppUser>("user");
            if (!user.Success || user.Value == null)
                return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new(new ClaimsIdentity())));

            var Claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Value.Username),
                new(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Rolename)
            };
            var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(Claims, "custom"));
            return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new(new ClaimsIdentity())));
        }
    }
    public async Task Login(AppUser user)
    {
        try
        {
            await _storage.SetAsync("user", user);
            var Claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username),
                new(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Rolename)
            };
            ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new(new ClaimsIdentity(Claims, "custom"));
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal)));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new(new ClaimsIdentity()))));
        }
    }
}
```

I registered this Authentication State Provider and Add Authentication like this

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthenticationState>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "custom";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "custom";
});
```

Now everything like Login, AuthorizeView and AuthorizeView with Role works but when I want to protect Routable components with **@attribute [Authorize]** I get an exception which says

> InvalidOperationException: No authentication handlers are registered. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddSomeAuthHandler?

I tried to give Authentication Scheme in Authorize Attribute like this **@attribute [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "custom")]** but it still didn't work and I get same error.

Any help from experts appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the auth related lines from Program.cs ?

Comment: This is everything related to Auth, I didn't write anything else

Comment: @Stefan No I had to opt for Built-in Authentication for this very reason. I've customized it to work with my own logic.